# Pagseguro não redireciona com código da transação

Tags: php, api

Estou utilizando a API do pagseguro em php para que **após o pagamento** o cliente seja redirecionado para uma página específica, ja configurei em **Aplicação > Página de redirecionamento** a url e o parâmetro que desejo receber via GET. Como estou utilizando a API ele parece ignorar esta configuração no painel e somente redireciona o que eu defini no código desta maneira:

```
private $redirectURL = http://meusite.com.br/site/cadastro/";

$this->curl = new \PagSeguroPaymentRequest();
$this->curl->setRedirectUrl($this->redirectURL);
```

A página é redirecionada para "http://meusite.com.br/site/cadastro/" mas preciso receber o código da transação junto com a url assim:

```
http://meusite.com.br/site/cadastro/transaction_id=E884542-81B3-4419-9A75-BCC6FB495EF1
```

Via API como posso definir o recebimento deste parâmetro na url?

Comment: Você configurou no pagseguro o parametro de redirecionamento ?
Não da para definir isso na URL, você precisa entrar na conta do pagseguro em lá na parte de integração que você seta o parametro de redirecionamento.

Comment: Sim, já configurei este parâmetro e também ja tentei sem o setRedirectUrl na API, apenas com a configuração de URL e parâmetro do painel, ele não redireciona após a compra.

Comment: Qual checkout está usando ?

Comment: https://ws.sandbox.pagseguro.uol.com.br/v2/checkout , estou usando no ambiente de teste v2

Comment: Está usando algum framework PHP, porque notei que esta usando url amigaveis.

Comment: Sim, Laravel 5.1. Parece que o link de redirecionamento não foi configurado, só funciona apenas quando passo a url na função via API, ignorando as alterações no painel da aplicação.

Comment: Em minhas implementações com pagseguro eu seto a url via código mesmo. Não testei via painel. Acho que é melhor você setar a URL via código mesmo

Comment: Tudo bem, mas no caso preciso do código da transação com o retorno da página, existe alguma outra maneira de pegar este código?

Comment: Da uma olhada nesse link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24744825/laravel-queries-strings